# Does git log --follow work for multple branches?

Tags: git, git-log

I recently see something very strange. Suppose I have three branches. They all have a file named A. A then is renamed to B independently in three branches. Then the three branches are merged into one. If now I use

```
git log --follow B
```

I think I should see three commits about the renaming like

```
diff --git a/A b/B
similarity index 85%
rename from A
rename to B
index b328642..5cd437a 100644
--- a/A
+++ b/B
```

But What I actually see is a commit about renaming from A to B like above, the other two are deleting A like

```
diff --git B B
deleted file mode 100644
index 5db3424..0000000
--- a/B
+++ /dev/null
```

It looks like to me that --follow ignores branches. It just follows through logs linearly rather than treat different branches differently.

What happens here? Is there any solution to avoid this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

log follows the first parent by default. So in this way, a merge is just looked at as another commit when it comes to follow.

Comment: But a merge has two parents, so which parent does it follow?

Comment: This makes sense for the sake of consistency. Beyond consistency, is there anything special about the first parent?